# Dynamically sort a list based on attribute selected by user in Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I am trying to sort a list with its member attribute by using `Comparator.comparing()`, and the attribute is selected by the user. Consider the case below:

```
public class MyClass extends BaseClass
{
    private String attr1;
    private Date attr2;
    private ChildClass attr3;

    //getter and setter
}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    private String attr1;
    private Date attr2;
    private int attr3;

    //getter and setter
}
```

This is what I have tried, but having compile error.

```
private Map<String, Function<MyClass, ?>> sortingOptions = new HashMap<>();
private String sortBy;  //sorting attribute selected by user

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    //my list to be sort
    List<MyClass> list = myService.getList();

    sortingOptions.put("attr1", MyClass::getAttr1);
    sortingOptions.put("attr2", MyClass::getAttr2);
    //......
}

//listener for sorting option changed
public void sortOptionChangedListener()
{
    //this line of code having error
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(sortingOptions.get[sortBy]));
}
```

The error showing is

```
The method comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (Function<MyClass,capture#3-of ?>)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be easier to simply store the method references in your Map rather than the Functions that you have now.   Consider this...

```
public class BaseClass implements Comparable<BaseClass> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(BaseClass o) {
        // implement this properly
        return 0;
    }
}

public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    private String attr1;
    private Date attr2;
    private ChildClass attr3;

    //getter and setter
}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    private String attr1;
    private Date attr2;
    private int attr3;

    //getter and setter
}

private List<MyClass> list;
private Map<String, Comparator<? super MyClass>> sortingOptions = new HashMap<>();
private String sortBy;  //sorting attribute selected by user

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    //my list to be sort
    list = myService.getList();

    sortingOptions.put("attr1", Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getAttr1));
    sortingOptions.put("attr2", Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getAttr2));
    sortingOptions.put("attr3", Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getAttr3));
    //......
}

public void sortOptionChangedListener()
{
    list.sort(sortingOptions.get(sortBy));
}
```

Comment: Clear solution. But there is no reason why `BaseClass` should implement `Comparable<BaseClass>`; the code runs fine without.

Comment: This is incorrect.  attr3 of MyClass is a ChildClass.  If ChildClass is not in some way Comparable, then the code will not compile.  Try it out.

Comment: Then you should make `ChildClass` comparable, not `BaseClass`. But since the question doesn’t contain a `MyClass::getAttr3` as sorting criteria, it raises the question whether it is really supposed to be that way, instead of, e.g. `Comparator.comparing(o -> getAttr3().getAttr1())`, `Comparator.comparing(o -> getAttr3().getAttr2())`, etc. Forcing `BaseClass` to be `Comparable` contradicts the obvious intention of sorting by a property. If `ChildClass` was supposed to have a natural order, it was `Comparable` already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Clinton's right. The following is the Comparator::comparing source code.

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Its parameters is a function whose input parameter is T and the return value is Comparable, this does not apply to a simple getter. I think reflection can do this, but more complex.

Comment: It is correct.  Try it out.  The comparing method will return a Comparator for MyClass.  All that it requires is a Function, that when given a MyClass object, will produce any other Comparable object.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I had a wrong understanding of Function before. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
private Map<String, Function<MyClass, ? extends Comparable>> sortingOptions = new HashMap<>();
```

You will probably have to live with warnings, one at the `sortingOptions`, another at `list.sort()`.

If you want this to be neater, you can make a helper method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T, U extends Comparable<U>> Function<? super T, ? extends U> getComparator(String sortBy) {
    return (Function<T, U>) sortingOptions.get(sortBy);
}
```

Usage:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(getComparator(sortBy)));
```

#### Update

You should do what Clinton recommended, that approach is more clean.